# trouble running flask on apache/mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run a basic helloworld with apache2 and mod_wsgi but depsite following the tutorial from flask documentation all i got is an error 500.

Everything is in /var/www/myapp

myapp.wsgi

```
from yourapplication import app as application
```

/etc/apache2/site-availables/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain

WSGIDaemonProcess myap user=web group=www-data  threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mydomain/myap.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/myapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup myap
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

hello.py (flask app)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should configure some kind of [logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/) so you can see the actual exception behind the 500 response.

Based on your code, you may be generating an ImportError in your WSGI file when you attempt to import `app` from `yourapplication` instead of `hello`.  Try:

```
from hello import app as application
```

You also have a couple of spots where you use `myap` instead of `myapp`, if what you posted here matches what's on your server. Either way, logging your errors should confirm it.

Comment: Apache/mod_wsgi does not suppress the error. If the errors in the the WSGI script mod_wsgi will log it to Apache error logs. Otherwise, unless you are in Flask debug mode, Flask itself will convert inner application errors into a generic 500 error page, so nothing gets to mod_wsgi to log. So is all about needing to enable Flask debug mode or setup Flask to log them in some other way which you do say, but that isn't a mod_wsgi issue.

Answer (score 2):

I notice 3 things:

1. Use the same name for your .wsgi and .py
2. Import your own program in the .wsgi module
3. You misspelled myapp to myap.wsgi in the apache configuration

Please make sure your code works using the Flask's webserver before trying to deploy to Apache.
Your final code should look like this to work:

hello.wsgi

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/your/application')
from hello import app as application
```

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain

WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=web group=www-data  threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mydomain/myapp.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/mydomain>
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And finally, if any error occur you can track them in your Apache's folder, inside Logs/error_log. Turn on your debug mode in Flask as Graham said and you will see any error in your application and better explain here.
Basically you just have to change this in your hello.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```